# How to check whether C# lambda expression is "empty"?

Tags: c#, function, lambda

Good day to everyone! Let's say, that I have a function, containing lambda expression in 2 variants:

```
DoSomething('a', x => { });
DoSomething('b', x => { Console.WriteLine(x); })
```

Farther in program I need to perform some actions, based on whether the method in the expression contains some code or not. In my mind it must look something like this:

```
 public void DoSomething (char symbol, Action<string> execute)
    {
        if (execute.Method.IsEmpty)
            DoThis(...)
        else 
            DoThat(...)
    }
```

But, of course, I'm unable to write exactly this. So, how can I check if there are commands in the function?

Comment: That's not sensible, use DoSomething('a', null) instead.  Now it is simple.

Comment: The `Action` that is being passed in is the same as any other function - you're not *supposed* to be able to tell what it does.  If you need to have one path where the caller provides an `Action` and another path where the caller provides nothing, provide a method overload that doesn't take an `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like two separate methods:

```
public void DoSomething (char symbol)
{
    DoThis()
}

public void DoSomething (char symbol, Action<string> execute)
{
    if (execute == null) /* handle null case */ 
        DoThis()
    else 
        DoThat()
}
```

Another option could be optional parameter (and you should check for null either way) :

```
public void DoSomething (char symbol, Action<string> execute = null)
{
    if (execute == null)
        DoThis()
    else 
        DoThat()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try looking at the corresponding IL of the action:

```
public void DoSomething(char symbol, Action<string> execute)
{
    byte[] body = execute.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    if ((body.Length == 1 && body[0] == 42) || (body.Length == 2 && body[0] == 0 && body[1] == 42))
    {
        // 0 - no op
        // 42 - return
        DoThis(...)
    }
    else
    {
        DoThat(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is horrifically kludgey. You shouldn't be peaking at IL to make code decisions. And what if the action calls a method that does nothing? You can't tell that way.

Comment: If the action calls a method that does nothing, then the initial action does something - it calls a method :-) Also chances are that in release mode, if the calling method is empty, the C# compiler will simply optimize it away. I agree with you that this is very brittle but depending on the actual scenario which unfortunately the OP hasn't quite shared with us it might be worth knowing.